# How to query for songs from artists a user is following when a song can have multiple artists?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have a specific query that I need for my home page feed to display all songs from artists a user follows with the caveat being that a song can be associated with multiple artists. I have the current schema:

```
// user table
type User {
    id: Int
    username: String
}

// artist table
type Artist {
    id: Int
    name: String

// a user can follow several artists
type UserArtist {
    id: Int
    UserID: Int
    ArtistID: Int
}

// song table
type Song {
    id: Int
    title: String
}

// songs can be associated with multiple artists
type ArtistSong {
    id: Int
    ArtistID: Int
    SongID: Int
}
```

So on my home page, I would like to query for all songs from artists that a user follows. One issue I have been dealing with is how to make a query for the following scenario...what if the user follows both `artists` associated with a `song`? I would only like to return a single unique song instead of the song being returned twice.

I had this all figured out when there was just a single artist associated to a song since there was no `ArtistSong` join table and a `artistID` on the `Song` table. So using `sequelize.js`, I did:

```
const user = await User.findOne({
  //query params here
});

// this queries for all artists in the UserArtist table that the user follows
const artists = user.getArtists();

// I then extract the artist Ids
const artistIds = artists.map((artist) => artist.id);

// Then I construct a query to search for all songs with those specific artistIds
// I use an OR query to search for all songs from the artists a user follows
const songs = Song.findAll({
    where: { 
        artistID: {
            [Op.or]: artistIds
        }
    }
})
```

This worked great, but as I mentioned, my schema structure changed since I need to account for multiple artists associated with a song. I use `sequelize.js` but also open to a raw query to handle this!

Thank you!

Comment: use a raw query. select * from song where id in (select distinct SongID  from ArtistSong where ArtistID in (select ArtistID from UserArtist  where UserID = #UserID#))

Comment: @jin making progress! If I needed to join the many artists associated to a song so they would return in my `SELECT *`, how would I do that since I can't just `INNER JOIN Artist ON Song.ArtistID = Artist.ID`

Comment: if you want to show  the song with artists info. it will make sql more complicate(need group by song and join three tables). i will recommend to change UI. like click each song and show the detail info.

Comment: @jin the UI needs to display the artist with the song honestly..I've sort of got it figured out, I think? `SELECT * 
        FROM Songs
        JOIN ArtistSongs ON Songs.id = ArtistSongs.SongID
        JOIN Artists ON Artists.id = ArtistSongs.ArtistID
        WHERE Songs.id 
        IN (SELECT 
            DISTINCT SongID 
            FROM ArtistSongs 
            WHERE ArtistID 
            IN (SELECT 
                ArtistID 
                FROM UserArtists 
                WHERE UserID = 1))`

Comment: this returns the artist with the song, only issue is that it returns two versions of the song if there are two artists associated. For example it will return Song 1 w/ Artist 1 and Song 1 w/ Artist 2

Comment: so need  contact with artists group by song.the sql will not efficiency.